# Cant open local html file with WebView on React Native canOpenURL: failed for URL

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, uiwebview, react-native-ios

```
    2020-01-29 20:32:22.470194+0300 Myapp[8905:2391245] 
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/146EA027-7A**/Myapp.app/assets/src/assets/policy.html" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme file"
```

I am getting this error on xCode console output on **real device**. On simulator, everything works fine.

Here is my simple full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const PolicyHTML = require('../assets/policy.html');



export default class PolicyScreen extends React.Component {


  render() {
    return (
            <WebView
            source={PolicyHTML}
            style={{flex: 1}}
            />
    );
  }
}
```

Couldn't find much solution about that online, what am i missing ?

Comment: did you add this HTML file as resource/asset in your XCode project?

Comment: No. Its only in react project folder

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me was just add `originWhitelist={['*']}` in the `<WebView>` component and then iOS would load HTML correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, i am using webview and wanted to load my local html file in that webview, which works perfectly fine in Android but was not in IOS device. After a lot of research i ended up with the following solution.

I have placed my html file in the following path:

```
MyReactNativeProjectFolder>app>views>monthly>trip.html
```

Where **monthly** is my custom folder that i created myself and has a local html file called **trip.html**.

And in the view, lets say **MyView.js**, where i want to call my html file i used the following syntax:

```
<WebView originWhitelist={['*']} source={require('./monthly/trip.html')} ref={( webView1 ) => this.webView1 = webView1} />
```

**MyView.js** is in the follwing path:

```
 MyReactNativeProjectFolder>app>views>MyView.js
```

If you are not getting any error on simulator then this shall fix your problem, otherwise try changing the html file path as I have mentioned above, that is in the views folder, and try again.

I hope this may resolve the error **Unable to open URL file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/146EA027-7A/Myapp.app/assets/src/assets/policy.html**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is this can be considered as proper solution but here how i solved it;

I am not sure but as my thinking Xcode is not allowing some codes on html files, so I thought about that found some websites on google which converts to html files to 'clean html file' and removes the unnecessary codes. After cleaning I replaced the new clean file with old one and it worked.

Hope it helps (Especially in Privacy Policy Files).